# How to set ejs data to data atribute and parse it in client side js?

Tags: javascript, json, express, ejs

I am trying to send leaderboard data from the server to the client side javaScript. Heres my server side javascript.

```js
const leaderboard = [[dog,cat],[car,bus],[foo,bar]]

const toJson = JSON.stringify(leaderboard)
        res.render('games/dodge.ejs', {
                leaderboard: toJson
 })
```

Here is how my ejs file recives it

```
<div data-leaderboard="<%= leaderboard%>"></div>
```

and then there is the clientside js ***dodge_leaderboards.js***

```
const leaderboardData = document.querySelector("[data-leaderboard]")

console.log(leaderboardData)
```

When I run this code it returns an error that says **Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'leaderboardData' has already been declared (at dodge_leaderboards.js:1:1)**
Also the console.log returns null.

I am trying to assing the arrays inside the big array to own variables, but now I am having problems with just a simple console.log. What do you think is causing the problem, I am also curios to hear how to parse the array.

Comment: It sounds like you've just tried to load dodge_leaderboards.js twice so it errors because you have a global `const` in it. This has absolutely nothing to do with data attribute.

Comment: @Quentin Lol you were right I accidentally had called two scripts in the ejs. But why does it return null tho? When I remove the const from leaderboardData it console.logs the whole div and the content can be seen inside of it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it working I forget to put ".dataset.leaderboard" after the leaderboardData

```js
const leaderboardData = document.querySelector("[data-leaderboard]")

console.log(leaderboardData.dataset.leaderboard)
```